# Devexpress 18.2.7 PivotGridControl C# - How to add a custom tooltip to a cell

Tags: c#, devexpress-windows-ui

I want to add tooltip to cell but it works only row or column tooltip.
Apperance doesn't have tooltip property.

A = The area I want to add tooltip
B & C = Fields that can be added

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uNYG.png)

There is my code. Is there any solutions or features?

```
private void PivotGridControl1_CustomAppearance(object sender, PivotCustomAppearanceEventArgs e)
        { 
            if (condition1)
            {
                ....
                if (condition2)
                {
                    ...
                    if (condition3)
                    {
                        if (condition4)
                        {
                            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(235, 235, 235);
                            // Tooltip
                            e.DataField.ToolTips.ValueText = "DataField ValueText";
                            e.ColumnField.ToolTips.ValueText = "ColumnField ValueText";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private void pivotGridControl1_FieldTooltipShowing(object sender, PivotFieldTooltipShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            // tooltip
            if (condition1)
            {
                e.Text = "Hittt";
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you should use [TooltipControler](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.Utils.ToolTipController)

Comment: I tried that but not worked in my case.